# How to create object instances with unique properties in Blender?

Tags: text-object, instances

Is it possible in Blender to create several instances of an object (Alt+D) and then to change some properties for one of them? (i.e. creating an instance with unique properties)
In particular, I am interested in created instances of "Text" object  with different text in them.

Answer (score 1):

`Alt + D` creates a linked duplicate. You could just duplicate using `Shift + D`. Then each duplicate has its own copy of the properties and modifications are just to that object.

Alternately if you already have the linked duplicates (and only want have unique text), then go to one that you want to have a unique text and click the number button (number of users of this property). This creates a new data block, which you can then have different text (and text format) assigned to it.

[image]

Comment: [1]. Are you sure it's Ctrl+D and not Shift+D? (Because nothing happens when I press Ctrl+D). [2]. And the second problem is: when I click on the "number button" (from your screenshot above) I can type unique text, but the other properties (like Font size, "Text Box" size) are also became unique. I just thought that I can have different text with while preserving same properties.

Comment: [1] You are right - Shift + D (answer edited). [2] Unfortunately I think the text and the text data properties are are all tied together.